# Get the path of current project opened in Xcode plugin

Tags: xcode, plugins, path, project

I'm trying to create an Xcode plugin that should read all files contained in the project opened in Xcode and do further work with files names(Extract images names).
The question is how to get the directory/path of the main bundle of the project opened in Xcode.

Thank you.

Comment: I am also having same issue.. did you find that??

Comment: @Sachin No. But check this http://www.blackdogfoundry.com/blog/common-xcode4-plugin-techniques/

Answer (score 11):

Hi this way you can find the current project path from plugin

```
NSArray *workspaceWindowControllers = [NSClassFromString(@"IDEWorkspaceWindowController") valueForKey:@"workspaceWindowControllers"];

id workSpace;

for (id controller in workspaceWindowControllers) {
    if ([[controller valueForKey:@"window"] isEqual:[NSApp keyWindow]]) {
        workSpace = [controller valueForKey:@"_workspace"];
    }
}

NSString *workspacePath = [[workSpace valueForKey:@"representingFilePath"] valueForKey:@"_pathString"];
```

Comment: +1000. Don't use bundlePath or current working directory, those don't work.

Comment: @Sachin how did you know about those methods ?

Comment: @onmyway133 https://github.com/kaphacius/Xcode7-RuntimeHeaders

Answer (score -1):

See the `Apple` `Sandboxing` Guide : https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Security/Conceptual/AppSandboxDesignGuide/AppSandboxDesignGuide.pdf

If you want obtain the your `bundle` Directory:

```
NSString* bundle = [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath];
```

Comment: Sorry, this is not what I mean. When you are working on a plugin.The code you wrote will return Xcode's bundle path. that's because you are working on Xcode itself(check this[link] (http://www.blackdogfoundry.com/blog/creating-an-xcode4-plugin/)). So what I'm trying to know is how to get the path of the project that Xcode is opening.